# How to play a segment of a video in Android?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I am writing an android project, and just want to play a specified part of a video(**eg: 10s-15s**), So how to get the **data**(which I use it and can play from 10s to 15s **without the original video file**, of course the data contains the video's 10s-15s data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Media Extractor available on android from the SDK to extract the data. You will have to do this offline on a PC using PC tools.

But you can however implement what you want to do in Android, as follows ..

- Create a instance of `MediaPlayer` and set the source to the file you want to play.
- Prepare the mediaplayer
- `seek` to the 10th second.
- Start the playback using the `play`
- Keep querying the mediaplayer for the current time of the playback, when it hits 15 seconds, call `stop` on the media player.
  Or you can write a delayed message for your handler and `stop` the playback when you get the delayed message.